# Mejor forma para llevar consultas Paginadas

Tags: php, base-de-datos

Buenas tardes estimados,

Mi pregunta es esa: ¿Cual es la mejor forma de realizar o mostrar registros paginados?
No estoy muy seguro de a partir de que número de registros las bases de datos como mysql o postgres retornan las consultas de forma más lenta. Entonces, que es mejor? Hacer una consulta que traiga por ejemplo 100 registros y luego de eso realizar la páginación manteniendo las registros en sesión, o, hacer una consulta a base de datos por cada página consultada?

Comment: Si son para mostrarlos en una tabla puedes usar DataTables. Tu recuperas todos los datos de la base de datos y te realizarán la paginación con tantos valores como quieras por página.

Answer (score 1):

Lo ideal es hacer una consulta a base de datos por cada página consultada mostrando todos los datos cada vez por una razón simple: **Consultas la información que requieres cada vez que la requieres**.

La diferencia está en cómo hacer las consultas. Es decir, decidir entre:

- Recargar la pagina cada vez que se hace una peticion al servidor.
- Cargar los datos de manera asíncrona.

Solo mostrar lo requerido es poco importante cuando se tiene una cantidad pequeña de datos, pero cuando se trabaja con grandes volúmenes hay algunos problemas con los cuales lidiar, por ejemplo:

- [Memoria agotada](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4096582/4987172)
- [Tiempo de ejecución del servidor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5164930/4987172)

Y del lado de la base de datos siempre cuentas con la instrucción [Limit y Offset](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp) para solventarlo.

Comment: Perfecto. Muchas gracias.